# Firebase in c# (API recommendation)

Tags: c#, .net, firebase

I am trying to make a simple program using a firebase database. But i would like to code my client in C# is there any good APIs available? I found a few but some are lacking functions and i would like to know the opinion of someone more experienced in these waters.

Comment: use this lib. it works very well https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is [a REST API which is fairly portable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/), and you can use this from any .NET language on any supported platform. [Dina Cruz has a thorough example of using this API](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/03/c-example-of-using-firebase-rest-api.html), and you could easily convert this info and use the portable/basic `HttpWebRequest` type from the BCL instead of whatever Dina used, for example, this is a transliteration of the first POST example from Dina's blog:

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    user = "UserNameValue",
    message = "MessageValue"
});
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://tm-admin-test.firebaseio.com/.json");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var response = request.GetResponse();
json = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
// TODO: parse response (contained in `json` variable) as appropriate
```

There are also several open source projects including [Fire#](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp), [FirebaseDatabase.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) and [FirebaseSharp](https://github.com/bubbafat/FirebaseSharp). I'm not sure if these support "all the things."

#### References

- [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) on google.com
- [C# example of using Firebase REST API](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/03/c-example-of-using-firebase-rest-api.html) on dinacruz.com
- [REST examples in C# using `WebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post) on StackOverflow.com
- [Fire#](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp) project on github.com
- [FirebaseDatabase.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) project on github.com
- [FirebaseSharp](https://github.com/bubbafat/FirebaseSharp) project on github.com

Comment: This is really helpful, as I'm trying to produce a similar API